# How to capture shift-tab in vim

Tags: vim, keyboard, x11, xterm, sunos

I want to use `shift-tab` for auto completion and shifting code blocks visually. I have been referring to [Make_Shift-Tab_work](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Shift-Tab_work) . That link talks about mapping `^[[Z` to `shift-tab` . But i don't get `^[[Z` when i press `shift-tab`. i just get a normal `tab` in that case.

It then talks about using `xmodmap -pke | grep 'Tab'`  to map tab keys. According to that the output should be

```
keycode 23 = Tab
or
keycode 23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab
```

However i get

```
keycode  22 = Tab KP_Tab
```

if i use `xmodmap -e 'keycode 22 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab'` and after that `xmodmap -pke | grep 'Tab'`, I still get

```
keycode  22 = Tab KP_Tab
```

This means running `xmodmap -e 'keycode 22 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab'` has no effect.

In the end the link mentions using `xev` to see what `X` recieves when i press `shift-tab`. But i dont have `xev` on my system.

Is there any other way i can capture shift-tab in vim

Comment: Does `xmodmap` print nothing? Any error code after running `xmodmap`? What OS (what distro)?

Comment: `xmodmap -pke | grep 'Tab'` prints `keycode  22 = Tab KP_Tab`. I am using SunOS 5.10

Comment: `xev` is typically included in an X utils package.  What the specific package name is will vary depending on your Linux distro, but it's `x11-utils` on Debian/Ubuntu and `xorg-x11-utils` on Fedora/RH.

Comment: It'd also be useful to know which terminal you're using.  Similarly, try this in xterm and see if it works there.

Comment: I was meaning does `xmodmap -e ...` print something? And check whether `xmodmap -e 'keycode 22 = Tab T'` work. It must echo nothing and map `<S-Tab>` to `T`.

Comment: You can also try to map `<S-Tab>` to some unused symbol, for example 0xffff (`xmodmap -e 'keycode 22 = Tab 0xffff'`). If I do this it produces `<ESC>[3~` in my terminal, so if it works you will only have to set `t_kB` in your vimrc.

Comment: for me `xmodmap` does not seem to work, i dont see any change after running `xmodmap -e 'keycode 22 = Tab T'`

Comment: i ran it with verbose options and this is what i got. `xmodmap:  unable to open file 'keycode 22 = Tab A'` for reading
`xmodmap:  1 error encountered, aborting.`. So it seems i dont have permission to change the file which xmodmap is changing. Is it possible to define such a file in my home directory

Comment: No, you just typed the command incorrectly.  The string `'keycode 22 = Tab'` must come immediately after the `-e` flag.  Otherwise, xmodmap treats the argument as a file that it is supposed to be reading.  So the command you want to run is `xmodmap -verbose -e 'keycode 22 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab'`

Comment: ok that was my mistake, but even when i run `xmodmap -verbose -e 'keycode 22 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab'` and then `xmodmap -pke | grep Tab` i get `keycode 22 = Tab KP_Tab` instead of `keycode 22 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab`. This means my `xmodmap -e` command has no effect

Comment: Is there systrace (strace) available on your system? Try installing it and running `strace -o /tmp/strace.log xmodmap -e 'keycode 22 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab'`, then paste the contents of `/tmp/strace.log`.

Comment: i cant run strace, i dont have access permission to /dev/log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link talks specifically about getting `^[[Z` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in insert mode.  If you leave off the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, then Vim will behave just as if you pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

The easiest way to make Vim recognize `<S-Tab>`, is to directly set the `t_kB` option to the escape sequence your terminal sends, instead of messing with maps.

As a quick test, try this in a running Vim:

> :set t_kB=<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>[Z
>   :imap <S-Tab> foo

Now when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in insert mode, `foo` should be inserted.  If that worked, you can make the change permanent by adding the following to your vimrc.

```
exe 'set t_kB=' . nr2char(27) . '[Z'
```

Comment: even after doing this `Shift+Tab` behaves just like a `tab`

Comment: actually i am not sure what escape sequence my terminal is sending when i press `shift-tab`. Is there a way i can check that

Comment: Yes, that's what `<C-v><S-Tab>` should be doing.  You don't have to do it in Vim.  From your shell, run `cat` and then press `<C-v><S-Tab>` and you should see what your terminal generates for `<S-Tab>`.

Comment: What does `egrep 'XK_[a-zA-Z_]*Tab' /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` show?

Comment: #define XK_Tab                  0xFF09
#define XK_KP_Tab               0xFF89
#define XK_ISO_Left_Tab                                 0xFE20
#define XK_Tabovedot           0x12d7

Comment: Those all look fine.  You have `ISO_Left_Tab` available, so you should be able to set that as the shifted version of Tab.